# how do i add css style in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills tabscount">
        <li ng-repeat="section in submissionCtlr.submissionForm.sections" ng-class="{ active:submissionCtlr.isSelected(section.sectionId) }" > <a href="" ng-click="submissionCtlr.selectTab(section.sectionId)">{{section.sectionName}}</a></li>
    </ul>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submissionCtlr.submitForm()" ng-disabled="submitForm.$invalid">
```

```
this.tab=1;
this.selectTab = function(setTab){
 var tabcount = $scope.submissionCtlr.submissionForm.sections.length;
 if(this.tab != tabcount){
     this.tab++;
 }else {

 }
```

On click next button i got count, at the end of li count need to submit. submit should be display and next should be display: none. how can i acheive in anugularJs.

Comment: what is your question exactly. you have already added a ng-class using which you add css based on expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) to tell that if the current tab(`tab`) is the same as the total number of tabs(`submissionCtlr.submissionForm.sections.length`).

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-show="submissionCtlr.tab==submissionCtlr.submissionForm.sections.length" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submissionCtlr.submitForm()" ng-disabled="submitForm.$invalid">
```

Comment: Now next button and submit working fine. can i make previous button same way?

Comment: @user1863480 what do you want to do with prev button

Comment: @user1863480 may be add `ng-hide="submissionCtlr.tab<=1"`

Answer (score 0):

For modifying the DOM elements in angularjs. The proper way is to create a directive and access the element in that directive.
For example -

```
<button  class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit()" on-submit> Submit </button>
```

JS:

```
 angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('onSubmit', ,function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope,el) {

              $scope.submit = function() {
                          el[0].css("display", "none");  //change the css here accordingly.
                        }     

        }

     };

    });
```

You can also add the class like

```
element.addClass('myclass');
```